# Change width and height of MaterialDatePicker in Android

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-datepicker

Users of my app use 10", 15", and 22" android tablets.  I'm employing the MaterialDatePicker control to allow them to choose dates in an activity.  I'm getting complaints that the numbers in the calendar are too tiny and hard to hit in just the right way.  I'd like to make the entire control 30% larger.  I was able to set the theme upon creating the control:

```
            val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
            builder.setTitleText(R.string.label_end_date)
            builder.setTheme(R.style.MaterialDatePickerStyle)
```

I was able to increase text size:

```
<style name="MaterialDatePickerStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

android:Width has no effect, scaleX/scaleY aren't doing the job either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change `android:textSize` in this way since it is not an attribute theme.
To change the dimension of the text used in the days you can use something like:

```
   <style name="MaterialDatePickerStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="materialCalendarDay">@style/Widget.App.MaterialCalendar.DayTextView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.MaterialCalendar.DayTextView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.DayTextView">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceBody1</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Are my only options textAppearanceBody2 and textAppearanceBody1?  the difference is very slight

Comment: @Jarrette it is just an example. You can define your custom textAppearance

Comment: So I'm guessing using "declare-styleable" in some way?  I've never created a custom attr before (yeah, I know).  I'm playing with some of the predefined ones but the area where you tap your finger looks to be staying the same, just the font-size increasing.  Is there not a way to make the whole calendar bigger and easier to tap?

Comment: @Jarrette it is easier. It is just a style [like it](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.1/lib/java/com/google/android/material/typography/res/values/styles.xml#L97).